# Run CMD as process in the background and starting external program. How do I know, if external program has exited

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, process

I start the CMD in the background as a process. With the process I start external programs. How do I know, if the external program has exited?

Comment: Are you executing a bat file that runs other programs or are you executing one or more programs from your C# app? It would help if you provided a simple code example that shows exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: FileName = "cmd", Arguments = "/K set prompt=INPUT -$G$S"
This is how i run cmd in the background. I then execute programs with process.StandardInput.WriteLine(); And here I need a way to know if the executed program has exited. process.Exited will not help, because the cmd process is running.

Answer (score 0):

If you only run the external program in the batch file you can use Process.Exited event.

```
process.Exited += Process_Exited;
```

If not, you can try to find the external process by name to know whether it has exited.

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(ExternalProcessName);
bool exited = processes.Length < 1;
```